# Cant save data in multiple tables using cakePHP 3.7

Tags: php, postgresql, cakephp, associations

Been trying to save data into other table when saving Fisica entity to the Database, since I am new to cakephp it seems impossible right now, have seen multiple posts, videos, documentations and none seems to work. Please somebody help me figure out what is wrong with that.

I found a huge mistake in my relations between the entitys, now it works like that:
Fisica belongsto Pessoa

**associations at FisicasTable.php**

```
$this->belongsTo('Pessoa')
        ->setForeignKey('id_pessoa')
        ->setJoinType('INNER')
        ->setClassName('Pessoas');
```

**Fisicas Controller**

```
$fisica = $this->Fisicas->newEntity();
    if ($this->request->is('post')) {
        $fisica = $this->Fisicas->patchEntity($fisica, $this->request->getData(),['associated' => 'Pessoa']);
        if ($this->Fisicas->save($fisica))...
```

**Fisica add.ctp**

```
<legend><?= __('Add Fisica') ?></legend>
    <?php
        echo $this->Form->control('nr_cpf');
        echo $this->Form->control('dt_nascimento');
    ?>
    <legend><?= __('Add Pessoa') ?></legend>
    <?php
        echo $this->Form->control('pessoa.vr_nome');
        echo $this->Form->control('pessoa.nr_telefone');
        echo $this->Form->control('pessoa.vr_email');
    ?>
```

I am getting the following error:
[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xAeKI.png)

I expected this code to insert in the two tables when submitting a new register to Fisica add.ctp.

Comment: What are some example fields from your `pessoa` and `usuario` tables, and what do your `$this->Form` calls look like to generate the inputs for them?

Comment: Copy the code from your view as requested above.  Also, have you inspected the entity after trying to save? Are there any errors in the entity->errors property? It could be a validation issue if such is set on the related models.

Comment: I changed some things in my implementation and added to the question the asked above code, but i still cant save, sorry for bothering you guys with that...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that i had an issue naming my tables in the database combined with the primary key naming pattern. Simply updating the names of the tables to "Fisicas" and "Pessoas" and changing their Primary and Foreign key's to fisica_id and pessoa_id and generating all the code with bake (cake bake all pessoas, for example) resolved the problem (and generated the associations automatically).

Answer (score -2):

You have to get all the tables that will store the data, can you please see the documentation https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/saving-data.html#saving-with-associations
example of code is

```
// Prior to 3.6.0
$articlesTable = TableRegistry::get('Articles');

$articlesTable = TableRegistry::getTableLocator()->get('Articles');
$author = $articlesTable->Authors->findByUserName('mark')->first();

$article = $articlesTable->newEntity();
$article->title = 'An article by mark';
$article->author = $author;

if ($articlesTable->save($article)) {
    // The foreign key value was set automatically.
    echo $article->author_id;
}
```

Comment: i didint tried, but this way is still valid in the 3.7>? looking at the docs, i only needed to create the association...